# Export project to a zip with all sources, dlls, etc?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a tool that inspects a CS 2008 project and created a bundle of all files that can unpacked on a different machine to build the project?

Basically I would like to give this to a smarter colleague and so he can help me figure out why it is not fetching the records it should :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a little utility to grab `<HintPath>`, `<Content Include=.../>` and `<Compile Include=...>` from the `.csproj` file. I am sure it is missing lots of stuff but I can add it as I go along.

Until something more useful comes up, this will have to do to.